# upload file by ajax, javascript,php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

please i want to upload file by ajax and javascript,php without refresh the page :
my idea is to send file by ajax xmlhttp.send(file); and get the file in script php, but i don't know how to do this uing function record

```js
function record(elem){
     
  }
```

```html
<td style='font-size:11px;'><span id='confirm1 $id'>Confirm : <input id='confirm1' onchange='record(this.id);' style='font-size:9px; height:27px; width:134px;' type='file' name='confirm1' /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like the FormData API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

An easier method may be to just use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is how to get the file in script php :
$_files['thefile']:

```js
function record(elem){
  var quelr=elem;
  var file1 = document.getElementById(quelr);
  var path = file1.value;
  var file = file1.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("thefile", file);

  
 var startIndex = (path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? path.lastIndexOf('\\') : path.lastIndexOf('/'));
 var filename = path.substring(startIndex);
 if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
  filename = filename.substring(1);
 }
 alert(filename);
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert("mehdi");
       xmlhttp.open("POST","record.php",true);
    alert("mehdi");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
       document.getElementById(quelr+" "+id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
```